# Java Hashmap object to XML in a specific folder

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, directory

I am trying to send an Hashmap object into an XML file. My object is declare as follow:

```
@XmlRootElement
Public class myObjectToHashmap
long id;
boolean bool;
String name;
long date;

public static void GetMyObject(long id,boolean bool, String name)
{
    myObjectToHashmap newObject = new myObjectToHashmap();
        newObject.id= id;
        newObject.date = new Date().getTime();
        newObject.name = name;
        newObject = bool;
    PlaceOfMyHashmap.myHashMap.put(id, newObject)
 }
```

Here is the location of my HashMap :

```
public class PlaceOfMyHashMap
{
    public static HashMap<Long, myObjectToHashMap> myHashMap = new HashMap<~>
}
```

Here is where I am trying to get my XML:

```
public class MainClass
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        MyObjectToHashmap.GetMyObject(1, true, "Mat")
        MyObjectToHashmap.GetMyObject(4, false, "Tommy")
        MyObjectToHashmap.GetMyObject(9, true, "Kate")

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyObjectToHashmap.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(PlaceOfMyHashMap.myHashMap , System.out);
     }
}
```

Then, I don't really get why it cannot generate anything, and I do not know how to add a location of the folder.

When I debug it is only saying that it is an invalid expression... Any tips ?

Here is the exception :

```
marshaller.mashal(~); Method threw 'javax.xml.bind.JAXBException' exception. 
errorCode = null linkedException = null detailMessage = "class.java.util.HashMap and none of its superclass are known in this context" 
detailMessage = "javax.xml.bind.JAXBException and none of its superclass are known in this context" 
stackTrace = {java.lang.StackTraceElement[6]@882 suppressedExceptions = size=0
```

Comment: What is an invalid expression?

Comment: this line : marshaller.marshal(PlaceOfMyHashMap.myHashMap , System.out);

Comment: Can you post the entire debug output?

Comment: I added them at the end of the post: 
marshaller.mashal(~); Method threw 'javax.xml.bind.JAXBException' exception.

errorCode = null
linkedException = null
detailMessage = "class.java.util.HashMap and none of its superclass are known in this context"
detailMessage = "javax.xml.bind.JAXBException and none of its superclass are known in this context"
stackTrace = {java.lang.StackTraceElement[6]@882
suppressedExceptions = size=0